# how to make 3 dimensional list of array in flutter dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i got stuck while code

here is the problem

> List jawabanTO = [];

after initialize that
i make this

> jawabanTO[int.tryParse(widget.A)!][int.tryParse(widget.B)!][C] = jawaban!;

but the flutter compiler keep saying error, anyone know how to fix this ?
best regards

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36) .....

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an index that doesn't exist in the list, namely this:

```
int.tryParse(widget.A)!
```

You'll have to either add (using e.g. `.add(foo)`) objects to each index/list as per your needs, or generate the lists with default values up front if you know an initial or fixed size. If you make the lists growable, you can also add objects later.

You can e.g. generate a 2x2x2 list as this:

```
final cube = List.generate(2, (_) => List.generate(2, (_) => List.generate(2, (_) => 0)));
```

Comment: im sorry, it was mistaken, i want to make an array of map inside array of map

so that must be cube[0]['map1][2]['map3']

how to solve this ?

thankyou so much btw

Comment: @SilentRoar, update your question in that case. Make it _very_ clear what you are after. Make sure it contains data example to avoid confusion.